# Extract data from form objects as array of values

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm building a web application using Symfony 2.5. I am currently struggling with internally forwarding requests with POST/PUT form data attached. I've had a previous a previous question resolved by [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad) concerning this point. For the full story see:

[Subrequests with post vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570086/subrequests-with-post-vars)

But now that I have the solution for forwarding, I can't seem to be able to find a way to extract form data as an array of values that could be attached to the sub request. I tried using `Form::getData()` but it returned an entity, I also tried to use `Form::all()` but I get an array of Form objects. I could iterate over all these to get the effective values in the form, but I feel like there should be a better solution.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you performing HTTP redirect you need to save all you form data to the Session before you redirect and than read it from the Session.

UPD: i found chapter in documentation that may help you [Using a Form without a Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class)

> This is actually really easy:

they said. 
If it doesn't help you can try one of conversion methods.

Simple "casting" (objects inside parent object will remains as objects):

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

or using `get_object_vars()`

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

or using `ArrayObject`:

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($object);
$array = $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
```

and finally JSON encode/decode

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Comment: Thing is, as said in the question, i am not redirecting i am forwarding (internally), so there's no new request from the browser.

Comment: Hi, I think the json encode/decode might be the solution, but I architectured things differently as to not have to forward requests between controllers. But i'll give it a try nevertheless